# __debugbreak() without connecting windbg

Tags: debugging, windbg, remote-debugging

__debugbreak() statement in a KMD results in a BSOD, if WinDbg is not connect.
I want to understand why?

I'm thinking the DUT and debugger exchange some artifacts..?

Comment: I would suggest you being more specific. As it is, the question is really hard to answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`__debugbreak`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f408b4et.aspx) intrinsic raises a breakpoint exception. (`int 3` on x86 systems)

Without a debugger, this goes unhandled, which will result in a bugcheck.

If you'd like to detect the presence of a kernel debugger, the [`KD_DEBUGGER_NOT_PRESENT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff548125(v=vs.85).aspx) variable might be of use to you.

`KD_DEBUGGER_NOT_PRESENT` isn't always up to date, but it can be refreshed using [`KdRefreshDebuggerNotPresent()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/wdm/nf-wdm-kdrefreshdebuggernotpresent).

You might need something like this:

```
void BreakIfDebuggerPresent()
{
    if (!KdRefreshDebuggerNotPresent()) {
        DbgBreakPoint();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

__debugbreak intrisic or  DebugBreakPoint api  both raise an int 3 exception

if you have it in usermode and it is unhandled the application crashes

if it is in kernelmode and is unhandled the os crashes

it is documented behaviour

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/wdm/nf-wdm-dbgbreakpoint

yif it is usermode and a kernel mode debugger is present  the exception is routed to kernel debugger  by default instead of crashing the app

you csn disable this behaviour by using kdbgctrl app in windbg installation